# Mysql & PHP : Display matrix table dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to built a matrix kind of table using PHP. The table structure of the MySQL is as followed below:

Table : Seats

```
id rows columns value
1  r1    c1      1
2  r2    c2      2
3  r3    c3      3
```

etc.. n number of rows and columns will have and the name also will be differ like a1,a2, b2,b3

I just want to display it like below:

```
    c1   c2  c3
r1  1    0   0
r2  0    2   0
r3  0    0   3
```

etc..

How do I display like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Idea here is to convert the table array to a two dimensional matrix with first and second column being the "keys" for the two dimensional matrix.

Now assuming you have got the array from table using SQL
following three Steps will do the magic:

1) Initialize a two dimensional matrix with keys from the columns of table array.

```
    // Initializing the two dimensional matrix with zeros
function initialize_2d($m, $value = 0) {
    $result = array();
    for ($i=1; $i <= $m ; $i++) {
        for ($j=1; $j <= $m ; $j++) { 
            $result['r'.$i]['c'.$j] = 0;
         }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

2) Assign the Corresponding Value to the Matrix

```
    // Assign values from Table Structure to Two Dimensional Matrix
function convert_2d($m_arr){
    $matrix_arr = initialize_2d(sizeof($m_arr));
    foreach($m_arr as $sub_arr)
    {
        $matrix_arr[$sub_arr[0]][$sub_arr[1]] = $sub_arr[2];
    }
    return $matrix_arr;
}
```

3) Prints the Matrix

```
    // Prints the 2D Matrix
function print_2d($matrix_arr){
    $table_html = '';
    $table_html .= '<table>
                    <tr><td></td>';
    foreach ($matrix_arr as $matrix_subarr) {
        foreach ($matrix_subarr as $key => $value) {
            $table_html .= '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
        }
        break;
    }
    foreach ($matrix_arr as $key => $matrix_subarr) {
        $table_html .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$key.'</td>';
        foreach ($matrix_subarr as $value) {
        $table_html .='<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
        $table_html .=  '</tr>';
    }
    $table_html .= '</table>';
    return $table_html;
}
```

Test above functions using following Test Code:

```
    // Array from Table
    $m_arr = array(array("r1","c1","1"),array("r2","c2","2"),array("r3","c3","3"));

    $matrix_arr = convert_2d($m_arr);
    $table_html = print_2d($matrix_arr);

    echo $table_html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query:

```
SELECT rows, columns, value
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY rows, columns
```

Then process the results in a loop. Whenever the `rows` value changes, start a new `<tr>` in your HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Barmar's response it would be easiest to treat the results from a DB query as an array, example below:

```
$sql = "Select * from yourtable order by rows, columns";
$results = mysqli->query($sql);

While ($row = $results-> fetch_array()){
   $rows[]=$row;
}

Foreach ( $rows as $row){
    $row['rows'];
    $row['columns'];
}
```

You will need to modify the foreach loop to add the HTML you are looking for. Additionally mysqli fetch array is discussed in more detail on following link: https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

You can loop trough your items from your database.
for each item you make a td and for each row you make an tr

for example

```
<?php

echo "<Table>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo       "<td></td>";
echo       "<td>C1</td>";
echo       "<td>C2</td>";
echo       "<td>C3</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo       "<td>r1</td>";
echo       "<td>1</td>";
echo       "<td>0</td>";
echo       "<td>0</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo       "<td>r2</td>";
echo       "<td>0</td>";
echo       "<td>2</td>";
echo       "<td>0</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo       "<td>r3</td>";
echo       "<td>0</td>";
echo       "<td>0</td>";
echo       "<td>3</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Instead of having text you could load it from a variable or you mysql text like this

```
<php?
 //everything is the same but here is an example of a <td>

$test = "hello world";
echo "<td>".$text."</td>";

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function matrics($int){
    $j = $int*$int;
    for($i=1;$i<=$j;$i++) {
        echo $i.' ';
        if($i%$int==0)
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
matrics(4);
?>
```